How can we connect to 2 different hive spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.uris
We need to read table from 2 different spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.uris, and do some validations.
I am not able to connect to both spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.uris at same time using sparkSession.
I will be using Spark version: 3.1.1 and language is scala.
Please comment out if any help.
